# Ag-gird: How to check if any leaf nodes has updated

Tags: ag-grid

We have used Ag-grid tree-data to display a file structure, and we can modify the file content after opening it.
What I want is to add some icon in tree node to indicate this file has been modified, what's the way Ag-grid should handle with this?

Current what I can think of is in every renderer to check if any of current node's leaf nodes have been modified, is there any better way to handle this?

E.g. If I know the modified nodeId, is there any quick way to know if the current node is the parent or (multi-layer parent) of this node. Or is there an API to get all leaf nodes of the current node.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this would be by using recursion.

This ag-grid [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/#example-file-browser) has a neat version of what you are looking for.

```
function isSelectionParentOfTarget(selectedNode, modifiedNode) {
  var children = selectedNode.childrenAfterGroup;
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (modifiedNode && children[i].key === modifiedNode.key) return true;
    isSelectionParentOfTarget(children[i], modifiedNode);
  }
  return false;
}
```